# DB2 Select Value from final table DELETE

Tags: db2, sql-delete

I haven't used the SELECT FROM FINAL TABLE clause much, but I was wondering if there was a way in DB2 to be able to select a value from a column in the same statement that I will be deleting that row.

I wasn't able to get an example working super quickly, and I was just curious if someone had a yes or no to this simple question.

Example:

```
SELECT COLUMN1 FROM FINAL TABLE (
    DELETE FROM [table]
     WHERE [condition]
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FINAL TABLE is not supported for DELETE.

Check out this list for suppoted combinations:

- OLD TABLE (only for UPDATE / DELETE)
- NEW TABLE (only for UPDATE / INSERT)
- FINAL TABLE (only for UPDATE / INSERT)

Comment: Great! That's all I needed! For whatever reason I wasn't able to find anything saying that DELETE wasn't supported. I'll mark this as the answer in 9 minutes when I'm allowed to

Comment: @SamWilliams that's because the _final_ table after deleting rows contains no rows (which have just been deleted) -- `FINAL TABLE` references rows affected by the DML statement _after_ they have been affected.